# Adding a dir to root in docker still wont allow git access

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a private git repo on bitbucket that I'm using to pip install a library. During my docker build, I copy the dir with the keys and config file into root. Then it pulls down the requirements and pip installs them.  (It pip installs fine when I'm just using my local terminal, so I know it's not the pip install.) However, I keep getting a

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights

If I remove the line in the Dockerfile that install the pip install that causes the image to fail, and then shell into the instance and pip install it works fine.

My directory looks like this:

```
app/
requirements.txt
docker_keys/
    .ssh/
        id_rsa
        id_rsa.pub
        config
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -qqy && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip uwsgi

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY docker_keys/.ssh /root/.ssh
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with how I'm copying the key dir into root.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Docker won't necessarily read from your identity file. Check `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to ensure something like this exists:

`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa"`

It's worth noting however that this is really insecure, and you shouldn't leave SSH private keys inside docker files.

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean in the docker image? Or on my machine/

Comment: inside the docker image